# Editing this Qt program (C++) I think

Tags: c++, qt, reverse-engineering

I am working on a raspberry pi project that I have picked up from a previous groups work. 
It seems that the program used to control the raspberry pi has been compiled and we can run it fine, however there is no original source code (C++) or any project files for Qt as far as I can see, below is a copy of the folder, is there any way to get at the source code using Qt or something else? 
We want to be able to make changes to the program.
There is no documentation on the build of the software, only indication on how to run it which we can do fine, I am trying to track down the authors but to no luck.

What can I try? I tried opening the files here with http://codelite.org/.
All of the object files and the turbo_gui file just contain one line: ELF SOH SOH SOH

[image]

Comment: There is at least _one_ source file, `moc_mainwindow.cpp`.  Does that have any useful code?

Comment: That's not a copy of the folder - that's a PICTURE of the folder.  You can get the executable from the Pi, but that's going to be in machine language, not human readable.  It would likely take somebody skilled in assembly many months to reverse engineer that.

Comment: @Andrew moc_* files contain informations about how Qt signals and slots are wired, with some code to make it work generated by Qt's meta-object compiler. You can get some insight about the original code, but it's just a compiler-generated file.

Comment: @Andrew, the other comments are correct, it is a file produced by QT compiling the project, nothing about the actual software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the image you posted, the directory is a Qt build directory, not a source directory.
The folder you showed contains some source files automatically generated by Qt, some compiled .o files and a linked binary, but not the original source code.

If the authors didn't publish the original C++ source code, there is no way to get the exact source code back. You should ask the authors to send you a copy of the source code.

If there is no way to get the source code, the best you can do is use a disassembler or decompiler (such as Hex-Ray's plugin for IDA) to get an idea of how the code works, then reimplement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, so best course of action is to chase down the originators, thank you I just wondered if there was an other way.

Comment: @JoshuaJones feel free to accept the answer if that's all you need ..